# What's the best way to get Epoch milliseconds in Perl?

Tags: perl, timestamp, epoch

It's easy to get Epoch-Seconds (timestamp) in perl:

```
time
```

But what's with milliseconds? The most effective way seems to be time*1000, but that's not as accurate as I want it to be. Any good hints except for the long terms documented @perldoc?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Time::HiRes](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/HiRes.html) module has a drop-in replacement for time

```
$ perl -E 'say time'
1298827929
$ perl -MTime::HiRes=time -E 'say time'
1298827932.67446
```

You can [read more in the perl FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-can-I-measure-time-under-a-second%3f)

```
perldoc -q "How can I measure time under a second"
```

Comment: Hm... I still get integer time with `Time::HiRes`. However, `clock_gettime()` from that module does the trick. It's perl 5.10.0

Comment: @Dallaylaen: did you export time from Time::HiRes?

Comment: Thanks, it was my mistake. Of course `use Time::HiRes qw/time/` works fine.

Answer (score 5):

A real world example would be:

```
use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday);
print gettimeofday;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -MTime::HiRes=time -e 'print time;'
```

For **Perl: v5.8.4** built for **SunOS** (sun4-solaris-64int), [oylenshpeegul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5134728/1910555) needs to be modified.